# Using script setup and reactive state vue 3 with toRefs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use script setup in my vue project.

Before using script setup, my script would be like this:

```
<script>
import Layout from '../containers/Layout.vue';
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    setup() {
        const state = reactive({});
        return {
            ...toRefs(state),
        };
    },
    components: { Layout, Layout }
}
</script>
```

Now I have it like this:

```
<script setup>

import Layout from '../containers/Layout.vue';
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'

const state = reactive({});
const props = defineProps({
    header: String
})


</script>
```

The thing that I am unsure about is how do I use the toRefs in this case? In the first case we are returning the variables so I understand the way we used `...toRefs(state)`
But now, how do I use it? Or is it not needed anymore?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`script setup` implicitly translate variable definitions

```
const a = ...
```

to

```
return {
   a: ...
}
```

There is no substitute for `return {...dynamicValue}` in `script setup`, which is intended to suite common use cases only. This would require to combine it with `script`.

`return {...toRefs(state)}` serves no good purpose because the resulting refs aren't used in script block. Even if they are, they are usually defined as separate reactive values instead of `state` object:

```
const a = ref(...)
const b = reactive(...)

return { a, b }; // Not needed in script setup
```

If there is ever a need to handle these values as a single object, they could be combined together:

```
const a = ref(...)
const b = reactive(...)
const state = reactive({ a, b });

return { a, b }; // Not needed in script setup
```

This works it the same way for both `script` and `script setup`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the values of the `state` reactive directly in script setup you can use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) like this :

```js
import { reactive, toRefs } from "vue"

const state = reactive({ name: "admin", age: 20 })
const { name, age } = toRefs(state)
```

Then you can access your values directly in the template

```html
<template>
    {{ name }}
</template>
```

However this is much less convenient to have to retype all of your properties